# Tcl namespace definition

Tags: namespaces, tcl

I can't find answer what is the difference in namespace definition using double :: ( when I read source files where both are used ) between:

```
namespace eval somenamespace {
}
```

and

```
namespace eval ::somenamespace {

}
```

sample without ::
https://github.com/tcltk/tcllib/blob/master/modules/generator/generator.tcl#L16

sample with ::
https://github.com/tcltk/tcllib/blob/master/modules/ftp/ftp.tcl#L56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit like path names. If you are in the root directory (the unnamed `/` path) it makes no difference if you use `bar` or `/bar`: both refer to the `/bar` directory. If you are in `/foo`, it matters very much if you use `bar` or `/bar`: the first refers to the `/foo/bar` directory, and the second still refers to the `/bar` directory.

`::` is like `/` for namespace names. In the root namespace (the empty `::` name) it makes no difference if you use `bar` or `::bar`: both refer to the `::bar` namespace. If you are in `::foo`, it matters very much if you use `bar` or `::bar`: the first refers to the `::foo::bar` namespace, and the second still refers to the `::bar` namespace.

Documentation: [namespace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm)

Answer (score 1):

In general, it depends on the context in which the code is run. If it is run in the global namespace, there is *no* difference between the two. If it is run inside another namespace (e.g., in `::foo` for the sake of argument) there's a difference (since one creates `::foo::somenamespace`).

For packages it makes little difference, the scripts provided by `package ifneeded` — and hence run by `package require` — are actually run by this line (inside `tclPkg.c`, in the function [`PkgRequireCore`](http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/artifact/5a42a927b02afb40?ln=497)):

```c
        code = Tcl_EvalEx(interp, script, -1, TCL_EVAL_GLOBAL);
```

That is, they're *always* in the global context, the `::` namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Donal